# CakePHP 3.0.1: DebugKit not working properly

Tags: cakephp-3.0, cakephp-debug-kit

I use CakePHP 3.0.1 and DebugKit (install using Composer).
I checked all steps to enable DebugKit but I don't see DebugKit Panel.
Help me!

Comment: Has the files been downloaded? I mean, do you see them on the plugins directory?

Comment: I used this command `php composer.phar require cakephp/debug_kit "3.0.*-dev"`. After running, I see the path is `/path_to_root_folder/vendor/cakephp/debug_kit`

Comment: You are right, there is where the files should be. Do you have `'debug' => true` on your config/app.php? Are you loading the plugin in your bootstrap.php?

Comment: Of courses. I checked them.

Comment: Which operative system are you using? do you have sqlite installed?

Comment: I am using Ubuntu 14.10, I installed php5-sqlite.

Comment: Did you installed cake using composer too? It already include debugKit, so you don't have to install it manually.

Comment: I guess the problem is your app tmp directory, make sure it is writable.

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you have the `pdo_sqlite` extension enabled for your php in the web server and that the tmp dir exists and is writable.